# Network connections only work if device connected via cable

Tags: c#, mysql, compact-framework, tcp, windows-ce

Ok, I tried for the last couple hours and I give up:
I develop for a mobile device (Win CE on Unitech HT660) and have a weird thing occurring:
I try to communicate with a service on my PC and I'm using TCPClient for it.

This works great except for one big problem: 
Once I unplug the USB-Cable I use to copy the files from VS on program start TCPClient throws a SocketException that no socket connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (not the case, Firewall is off, no third-party installed and the service is listening)

And it gets weirder: If the cable is plugged in and I remove it after the program made the connection everything works perfectly fine, I can send and receive data without the cable, I can just not connect without the cable.

Btw: It's the same story with MySQLConnection from the MySQL .NET Connector. It works with the cable, but if it is removed without an established connection no connection can be made.

Has anyone ideas on that?

Thanks in advance!

PS: One thing I forgot to mention: I use wireless to connect to my network, and IE as well as pinging the computer with the service and mysql database on it works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are the correct ports forwarded, to the right machine?

Comment: Omniscience: It's the same subnet for both, the WinCE device and the other machines, so there's no port forwarding. Or did I miss something that I need to configure?

Comment: Can you test connecting to the server port from another PC on the same network?  If another PC connects but the WinCE device doesn't then it's something on the WinCE device. If the other PC also fails to connect then it's probably something on the server machine.

Comment: Is the server binding to a specific address? Does the WiFi bridge/access point do any filtering?

Comment: when you have the USB cable connected, does it happen that activesync starts?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Vista / Win7, check if the wireless network is set as private / office network.
Having it set to public network causes very weird symtoms.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the good advice, however in the end it was nothing with my code or the network or the server. 
I checked it on another mobile device with no changes and it works.

Seems that the Unitech HT660 has some issue with TCP/IP connections under .Net. 
Googled this and I'm not the only one with this problem...